# php Output array values ​in the database

Tags: php, html, database

I entered the image files into the database through the input form.
The database contains elements of name, hash, and time.
When I upload multiple files, only 'Array' is outputted to the name.
I have to show the images on the view page.
I want to store elements of the array separately when storing them in a database, or to output elements of the array separately when outputting them.
Please help me

upfile.php :

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

upload.php :

```
if(!$_FILES['upload']['name'])
{
    echo "<script>alert('Emtpty');";
    echo "history.back();</script>";
    exit;
}

if(strlen($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 255)
{
    echo "<script>alert('Too long');";
    echo "history.back();</script>";
    exit;
}

$date = date("YmdHis", time());
$dir = "./dir";
$file_hash = $date.$_FILES['upload']['name'];
$file_hash = md5($file_hash);
$upfile = $dir.$file_hash;

$total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);

for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) { 
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])) {
        if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $upfile))
        {
                echo "upload error";
                exit;
        }
    }
}

@ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'DBid', 'Password', 'DBname');
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "DB error";
    exit;
}

$query = "insert into ftp (name, hash, time) 
          values('".$_FILES['upload']['name']."', 
          '".$file_hash."', '".$date."')";
$result = $db->query($query);
if(!$result)
{
    echo "DB upload error";
    exit;
}

$db->close();

echo "<script>alert('Upload');";
echo("location.href='./view.php';</script>");
```

If output the name, nothing is generated.

> name       | hash                             | time
>
> Array      | 6933b06c625e6900e1570298e0e2baf8 | 2019-08-09 01:35:47
>
> Array      | cecef12bb58ef31885bd1a0625909269 | 2019-08-09 02:28:51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey that is because when uploading multiple files, the $_FILES variable become as array:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo.txt
            [1] => bar.txt
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => text/plain
            [1] => text/plain
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /tmp/phpYzdqkD
            [1] => /tmp/phpeEwEWG
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 456
        )
)
```

and you are inserting as string and you should do a loop first.

```
foreach($_FILES['upload']['name'] as $file){
    $query = "insert into ftp (name, hash, time) values('".file."',..... 
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer!
I tried but it didn't work. I think I need more study..
Maybe I wrote it wrong. Look at it please

view.php :

`<?php
 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', "id', 'pw', 'db');
 
 $number = $_GET['number'];
 
 $query = "select * from ftp where number = $number";
 $result = $connect->query($query);
 $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 
 $src = $rows['name'];
 
 print_r($src);
?>
<img src='<?php echo $src?>' />`

Comment: Yeah, that is not gonna work, you should review the code. try to learn more about loops, arrays, multidimensional arrays. after trying to do a post with a form using input text to make it easier to understand.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) returns an array. print like this: $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); print_r($rows);

Comment: Don't forget to give me a thumb on my answer :)

Comment: Thank you! How can I give you a thumb?